# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError - unable to set InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm new to JavaScript and APIs. I'm trying to use the Open Weather API. I fetched the data, extracted the temperature from it. The temperature value gets logged into the console but won't get into the innerHTML of the element I'm trying to put it into.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1 id="current-time">11:11 AM</h1>
      <p id="greet-weather">Good Morning</p>
      <p id="#weather">123</p>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code snippet of the weather fetch:

```
async function getWeather() {
    let tempHolder = document.querySelector("#weather");
    const api_url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=<MYID>&units=metric";
    fetch(api_url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let tempValue = String(data["main"]["temp"]) + "° C";       
            console.log(tempValue);
            tempHolder.innerHTML = tempValue;
    })
}
```

And here is the console output I got:

```
28.09° C

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
at index.js:33:28
(anonymous) @ index.js:33 Promise.catch (async) getWeather @ index.js:35 (anonymous) @ index.js:41
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tempHolder` is `null` so you can't set the `innerHTML` of a `null`. Since `tempHolder` is a reference to the `#weather` element, the code isn't able to locate such an element.

Comment: Can you please tell me what I have to do to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and include all the relevant code (HTML, CSS) so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: @retr0bat: Given the updated code... You have a typo.  One of the `id` values in your HTML starts with a `#` character, the rest do not.  It shouldn't start with that character.

Comment: Added the HTML code. I don't think CSS effects the issue, so I'm not adding that. Will do it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been very kind and helpful. I'm gonna go sit in a corner wondering why I wrote a CSS-y thing in HTML.